# What are the exit codes for devenv.com/exe?

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, exit-code, devenv, return-code

Any command line application return code as exit codes that notify the host environment the final status of the instruction. VS command line: devenv.com return number of codes. Although there is no (or I can't find any) such list or post regarding this. Is there any documentation? If not, anyone from VS team can document this here?

Comment: `devenv` does set the `errorlevel` to nonzero when any project in the solution fails to compile; it might depend on `devenv` command line supplied parameters and switches. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] of a typical `devenv` command line and failing output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%errorlevel%` (cmd.exe) or `$LASTEXITCODE` (Powershell) will be set to `0` on success, any other value suggests a failure for `msbuild.exe` or `devenv.exe`.

Comment: Ugh I wish there was decent documentation for this. Our build literally outputs all builds succeeded, 0 failed yet devenv.com returns 1. Surely there is a way to find why devenv.com is throwing an error?

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2019 build 16.11.2, I found that performing a build with **devenv.exe** always sets the ERRORLEVEL to 0, while building with **devenv.com** sets ERRORLEVEL to a positive number if the build fails, or 0 if it succeeds.  **devenv.com** also waits for the build to finish before returning control to the shell.  Both **devenv.com** and **devenv.exe** support the **/Out** parameter for specifying a log file explicitly.  In addition, **devenv.com** generates console output which can be redirected to **nul** if not required.

So, running builds via a Windows batch file, you can run **devenv.com**, then immediately check for failure:

```
"C:\path\to\devenv.com" "my-solution.sln" /Rebuild "Release|x64" /Out "my-solution-build.log" > nul
if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Error %ERRORLEVEL% building my-solution.sln & goto my-failed-build-label
echo Build succeeded
. . .
```

In the above example, the test **if ERRORLEVEL 1** will be true if **ERRORLEVEL** is set to 1 *or higher*.

It is possible for post-build events within each project to encounter error conditions and to set an ERRORLEVEL, for example:

```
rem This is in a post-build event for a project
if not exist "path-to-expected-build-output.exe" exit /b 3
```

When **devenv.com** exits, these post-build ERRORLEVELs may get swallowed up and converted to an ERRORLEVEL such as 1.

Comment: We get error code 0 on success in devenv.com in vs2022 and earlier. 1 (non zero) is conventionally an error code not success.